# iOS Simulator Device Language doe not match Settings

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nslocale

My understanding is that the device language should be set via: Settings > General > Language & Region. [My device shows "English" as the language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flpDx.png), however when I open my app, certain text such as the [Apple sign-in method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXc89.png), and the "back" button for navigation links is in Arabic. I checked this by printing out the NSLocale.current.languageCode value, and ensured it was "ar", which did not match my expectation of "en".

I tried toggling the language from english to french, and back again to english, but the words never changed from arabic to anything else. I've also tried rebooting the simulator, erasing all content and settings, and using different target devices (iphone 13 and 11).

Comment: What is your app's development language set to? Look at your Info.plist and see what setting you have for "Development localization".

Answer (score 0):

After adding the "Localizations" node in the info.plist file, and setting the first item to "English", the formatting now looks as expected. Thanks for the comment @HangarRash. Still not exactly sure why this is needed since I expected it should be pulled from the simulator's language setting

Comment: If your app only supports one language then it will appear in that language, regardless of what the device is set to.